# On iOS, what's the benefit of OpenSSL over using CFStream, CFNetwork etc. for secure sockets?

Tags: security, sockets, ios, ssl, openssl

One obvious benefit seems to be the low level access you gain from using OpenSSL. But, I'd like to know if there's anything (important) that you can do with OpenSSL and not otherwise.

Comment: The low level access? Your question remains obscure.

Comment: @EJP I meant the methods to manipulate Cipher suites, certificates etc. I couldn't find any API related to cipher suites on iOS.

Comment: You should try asking this on the [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @AvidD Wow, cool new stack exchange, thanks. But I was looking for an iOS specific answer, really. I just could not wrap my head around the SSL features on the iOS and was considering using OpenSSL instead. So, I just needed to know if I'm really missing some functionality in the native API and if the trouble's worth the switch.

Comment: Well, I'm not much of an iOS expert, but one of the moderaters there, is a big one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked this again and the only benefit of OpenSSL seems to be it's range of cipher suites supported. Also, OpenSSL gives you a much granular control of the entire process, but this may be superfluous for most applications.

Answer (score 1):

[Secure Transport](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/secureTransportRef/Reference/reference.html) (the SSL/TLS implementation available on Mac OS X) is not available on iOS as of version 4.2.1. Third-party developers have to use the URL Loading System or CFNetwork (the latter optionally together with [NSStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002277-DontLinkElementID_1)).